# How do I determine if rpm installation is in progress?

Tags: linux, rpm

I'm writing a script where instructions must to fork depending on whether rpm installation is in progress at the moment.

I know how it is done with dpkg - if deb package installation is on, `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file is created and exists.

Is there something like that with rpm, or is there any other way to know that rpm installation is happening now?

Comment: I don't have an `rpm` distro to check, but according to http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Docs/RpmRecovery#Removingstalelocks there is a command to see if a process is holding a lock on the rpm database.

Answer (score 0):

See yum python code, which detects whether another (usually yum)
process is being executed.

There are too many layered locking schemes (usually) serializing
yo an rpmdb to give you a definitive answer. Old (i.e. last century)
versions of rpm used a fcntl lock on /var/lib/rpm/Packages to serialize
rpmdb access. Slightly more modern (like 10+ years ago) have used
the Berekeley DB concurrent access locking (which serializes
on a per-table level reader <-> single writer exclusion).

Even more modern rpm (like 5+ years ago) introduces transactional
per-page locks and ACID behavior, which is Yet another serialization
scheme.

Various depsolvers like yum/yast/urpmi have introduced other layers of
locking, unfortunately most of which are non-interoperable.

Short answer: There isn't one locking scheme to serialize
concurrent RPM (usually rpmdb) access that is widely deployed.
The most effective lde facto ocking is that provided by Berkeley DB because
that rpmdb access is usually the most contentious.